# Tap into logging events generated in this thread

Tags: log4j2

We all know how useful are log messages for debugging purposes. But sometimes logging gets buried under tons of now-useless other messages; this is specially true for some busy servers.

I'm planning to have some REST endpoints for system maintenance, and would like to collect all the logging messages and send them back over the HTTP connection. The REST response **IS** the collected logs. All the logging points are already there.

My idea was to add a custom `Appender` at the very beginning of a REST request, and remove it afterwards:

```java
@GET
public void request (@Context HttpServletResponse response) {
    Appender appender = new SpecialThisThreadOnlyAppender(response.getWriter())
    rootLogger.addAppender(appender);
    try {
        request0();
    } finally {
        rootLogger.removeAppender(appender);
    }
}
```

Is there already a `SpecialThisThreadOnlyAppender` ready for use (whichever name it has), or would this scenario amounts to abuse of log4j engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting idea but I am having difficulty determining the usefulness of this. You are creating a REST request that returns the logs as its response. But in that case what is the REST request supposed to be doing?  It doesn't return the results of whatever request0 is supposed to do so how is this useful to the application that wants to use this endpoint? Basically, it is only useful from curl or Postman. In order to be useful this would probably need to accept the service method you want to call as a parameter in the uri, but you would almost certainly never want an endpoint like that in a production environment.

Most people solve this problem by adding correlators to the log events. See [Log4j Audit Request Context](http://logging.apache.org/log4j-audit/latest/requestContext.html) for how Log4j Audit supports it, but you don't have to use that to implement it as it simply uses Log4j's ThreadContext to capture the relevant data. If you include a unique RequestId in each request and a unique SessionId (not the HTTP session id) for each user you can capture all of the same info assuming you are using some sort of log aggregation like ELK.

Also, if you use correlators in theory you could use the [RoutingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) to route to different locations based on one of the correlators.

Here are some other links to using correlators: [Fish Tagging Logs](https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/threadcontext-fish-tagging/) and [Logging Each Action of Every User](https://medium.com/@danismaz.furkan/logging-each-action-of-every-user-in-detail-with-spring-mvc-interceptors-and-log4j-2-threadcontext-8e648baa40e)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if not resolving the issue itself, it comes with a bunch of new information I didn't have before. Actually I myself am not very comfortable with what I was asking for.... it is a sort of dynamically adding and removing logging configuration (and that is usually static, configured by the system administrator).

Comment: The REST service does not produce any other answer. If not sending logging data back, it would produce just 200 or 500. It has side effects though.

Comment: This endpoint ought to be accessible only to administrators, people who already have access to the logs. It is just that the logs are busy. The real answer to this is: use a log aggregator to sort the log out. What I was (perhaps wrongly) trying to accomplish was a shortcut. The real problem here is corporation policy: to setup an aggregator would take a very long time, many authorization instances and perhaps added duties.

Comment: Even if you log to files, if you include the correlators in the pattern you can use grep or other tools to filter what you are seeing.